# how can I validate with vuejs fields that are prepopulated from database?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to validate the inputs from a form in vuejs, and when the data is pre-populated I want the inputs to convert to readonly.

```
<input type="number" name="cf_962" class="form-control" v-model="fillProfile.cf_962" step="0.1" :readonly="(fillProfile.cf_962>0.00) ? true : false">
```

the problem with this now is that always that i writed on the input if the value is higher than 0 the input is readonly and i dont want that.. how can do that with vuejs 2?.. thank you.

Comment: so do you want the read only property to be true in the case of `(fillProfile.cf_962>0.00)` or not, as that appears to be what the code you've provided does

Comment: Yeah the subject is that always validate when i write on the input and i dont want that i want the valitaion only when preload the data to my form.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying achieve can be done easily using v-once directive

```
<input type="number" name="cf_962" class="form-control" v-model="fillProfile.cf_962" step="0.1" :readonly="(fillProfile.cf_962>0.00) ? true : false" v-once>
```

As mentioned in docs

> You can also perform one-time interpolations that do not update on
>   data change by using the v-once directive, but keep in mind this will
>   also affect any other bindings on the same node

v-once will let you set readonly for the inputs having pre populated data, and not readonly for the inputs which are not pre populated. This thing will happen only once so next time you write on the input it will won't affect the readonly anymore.

Comment: Hello i maked the test with v-once as you told me above, but not working, the value from database is not populated on the input.. showing a input empty without value.